# select the right value in the drop down in jsp on edit

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

**ClientBean**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class ClientBean {
    private Integer clientid;
    private String clientname;
    private String paymenttype;
    private Date joiningdate;
    private String email;
    private ArrayList<String> paymentnames;
    public ArrayList<String> getPaymentnames() {
        return paymentnames;
    }
    public void setPaymentnames(ArrayList<String> paymentnames) {
        this.paymentnames = paymentnames;
    }



    public Integer getClientid() {
        return clientid;
    }
    public void setClientid(Integer clientid) {
        this.clientid = clientid;
    }
    public String getClientname() {
        return clientname;
    }
    public void setClientname(String clientname) {
        this.clientname = clientname;
    }
    public String getPaymenttype() {
        return paymenttype;
    }
    public void setPaymenttype(String paymenttype) {
        this.paymenttype = paymenttype;
    }
    public Date getJoiningdate() {
        return joiningdate;
    }
    public void setJoiningdate(Date joiningdate) {
        this.joiningdate = joiningdate;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

**ClientController**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView editClient(@ModelAttribute("command")  ClientBean clientBean,
            BindingResult result){
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("client", prepareClientBean(clientService.getClient(clientBean.getClientid())));
        return new ModelAndView("addClient", model);
    }


private ClientBean prepareClientBean(Client client){
        ClientBean bean = new ClientBean();
        ArrayList<String> modes = new ArrayList<String>();
        modes.add("Monthly");
        modes.add("Quaterly");
        modes.add("Half-Yearly");
        modes.add("Yearly");
        bean.setPaymentnames(modes);
        bean.setClientname(client.getClientname());
        bean.setEmail(client.getEmail());
        bean.setJoiningdate(client.getJoiningdate());
        bean.setPaymenttype(client.getPaymenttype());
        bean.setClientid(client.getClientid());
        return bean;
```

and

**addClient.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Add Client Data</title>
    </head>
    <script>src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <body>
        <h2>Add Client Data</h2>
        <form:form method="POST" action="/ClientDetails/save.html" onsubmit="return ValidateForm();">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="clientid">Client ID:</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="clientid" value="${client.clientid}" readonly="true"/></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="clientname">Client Name:</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="clientname" value="${client.clientname}"/></td>

              <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="paymenttype">Client Payment Type:</form:label></td>
                   <td><form:select path="paymenttype">
                        <form:options items="${client.paymentnames}" itemValue="{client.clientid}" />
                    </form:select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="joiningdate">Client Joining Date:</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="joiningdate" value="${client.joiningdate}"/></td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="email">Client Email:</form:label></td>

                  <td><form:input path="email" value="${client.email}"/></td>
                </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
              </tr>
            </table> 
        </form:form>


  <c:if test="${!empty clients}">
        <h2>List Clients</h2>
    <table align="left" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Client ID</th>
            <th>Client Name</th>
            <th>Payment Type</th>
            <th>Joining Date</th>
            <th>Client Email</th>
        </tr>

        <c:forEach items="${clients}" var="client">
            <tr>

                <td><c:out value="${client.clientid}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${client.clientname}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${client.paymenttype}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${client.joiningdate}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${client.email}"/></td>
                <td align="center"><a href="edit.html?clientid=${client.clientid}">Edit</a> </td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can we select the right value in the drop down of paymentNames in the jsp?.

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding `itemValue="paymenttype"` in `form:select`. Spring will select a option value matching by `path`.

```
<form:select path="paymenttype" itemValue="paymenttype">
   <form:options items="${client.paymentnames}"  />
</form:select>
```

**UPDATE**

Your model attribute name is "command":

```
@ModelAttribute("command")  ClientBean clientBean
```

But after you have updated your `client`, you are saving it in the different model attribute (i.e. client) name as follows:

```
model.put("client", prepareClientBean(clientService.getClient(clientBean.getClientid())));
```

Therefore the bind operation is not working properly.

**SOLUTION**

So, If you change your model name and form elements related it, it will probably works.

Model name same as @ModelAttribute("command"):

```
model.put("command", prepareClientBean(clientService.getClient(clientBean.getClientid())));
```

And Spring Form:

```
<form:select path="paymenttype">
    <form:options items="${command.paymentnames}"  />
</form:select>
```

**OR**

You can use model named `client`. But ,in this case, you should add modelAttribute="client" (or commandName="client") in spring form.

```
@ModelAttribute("client") ClientBean clientBean

model.put("client", prepareClientBean(clientService.getClient(clientBean.getClientid())));

<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="client">
 <form:select path="paymenttype">
    <form:options items="${client.paymentnames}"  />
 </form:select>
</form:form>
```

`Also:` Java follows camelcase syntax for naming the class, interface, method and variable. You should use `paymentType` instead of `paymenttype`.

Comment: thanks for the answer the same is not working for edit operation.